# Button value to be changed back to original value on timeout (form double submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fix a form double submit by disabling the submit button temporarily and changing the submit button value to "processing..." so the user knows what is going on.

The disable works `onClick` and the "Submit" value changes to "processing...", however I am unable to change the value back to "Submit" after the `setTimeout` function has ended.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    this.value = "Processing...";
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.value = "Submit"; //<- this line doesn't work
      $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `this` to `$("#submit_btn")` and it works:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#submit_btn").val("Processing...");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#submit_btn").val("Submit");
      $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The issue was that your functions were interfering with `this`. You could have done `self = this` which would have had the same effect:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    var self = this;
    $(self).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(self).val("Processing...");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(self).val("Submit");
      $(self).removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Or you could have used `event.target`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit_btn").click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(event.target).val("Processing...");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(event.target).val("Submit");
      $(event.target).removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Explanation is needed to understand why you did what you did (and I didn't downvote).

Comment: Oh yes @LGSon - I'll add that.

Comment: Awesome thanks man. I swear I tried that approach before I posted this question... must have forgotten a semi colon or something lol, rookie mistake. I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes when stackoverflow allows me. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(function() {
        $("#submit_btn").click(function(event) {
            $('button').button({ loadingText: 'Processing..' });
            $('#submit_btn').button('loading');
            //after submit stuff put below line to reset;
            $('#submit_btn').button('reset');
        });
    });
```

above code work best when you used
html button in place of input type button
Note-- To Show Spin Icon inside Button put 
 font-awesome or any other icon in place of Processing.. or both  in loadingText object

Comment: it prevent multiple click (submit) until first click event  completed by... disabling button  by default ,,

Answer (score 2):

you just need to replace that line with the following code:
 $("#submit_btn").val("Submit");

you should use val function to change the text of the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
            $("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            this.value = "Processing...";
            outerthis = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                outerthis.value = "Submit";
                $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem about the wrong usage of `this` keyword inside `setTimeout()` has already been explained. However, if you are able to use [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ([ES6 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Specifications)), that won't be a problem:

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although **without** its own bindings to the **this, arguments, super, or new.target** keywords.

Using this feature, your code can be simplified a little as shown on next example:

```js
$("#submit_btn").click(function()
{
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled").val("Processing...");

    setTimeout(
        () => $(this).val("Submit").removeAttr("disabled"),
        5000
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```